# How to access the json data from a jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, json

This is the json string that comes out of the json_encode() file:

```
[{"ID":"650","DESCR":"FRONTAGE","MAINURL":"images\/98\/30-HEATH (1).JPG","THUMBURL":"images\/98\/30-HEATH (1).JPG","ALBUM":"98"},{"ID":"651","DESCR":"PICTURE","MAINURL":"images\/98\/30-HEATH (2).JPG","THUMBURL":"images\/98\/30-HEATH (2).JPG","ALBUM":"98"},{"ID":"652","DESCR":"PICTURE","MAINURL":"images\/98\/30-HEATH (3).JPG","THUMBURL":"images\/98\/30-HEATH (3).JPG","ALBUM":"98"}]
```

This is the call I'm using. It does give an Object, however each time I try to access it, i get a type error from chrome javascript console.

```
function FindPictures(b) {

var picturesHome = {};
var album = "";
var baseURL = b;

this.pics = function(alb){
    album = "";


    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "picsJSON.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            picturesHome = json;
        },
        error: function (error) {}
    });

    return picturesHome;    
};

};
```

Comment: How are you expecting to use the FindPictures function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`success` is a callback: it wont be executed until the ajax download finishes, but your function will return `picturesHome` immediately. Standard procedure is to do some meaningful work in the `success` callback:

```
function doSomethingWithThePictures(pics)
{
    alert('got some pics!');
    console.log(pics);
}

... snip ...

$.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "picsJSON.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            doSomethingWithThePictures(json);
        },
        error: function (error) { alert('ERROR: ' + error); }
    });
```

Comment: since the code specifies `async:false`, it will be executed in the order of the statements. The actual problem comes from the `datatype`, i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

As i guess, the problem is with the specified datatype in the ajax call

this can be solved by either specifying the JSON content type in php like

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

or removing the `datatype` option from ajax and parse it to JSON like

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "picsJSON.php",
    success: function (json) {
        picturesHome = JSON.parse(json); // you can use $.parseJSON() instead
    },
    error: function (error) {}
});
```

hope this helps